# PHP simple HTML dom parser and preg_split because clear <html> tags are missing

Tags: php, regex, dom, web-scraping, html-parsing

I have a website that uses external data from a variety of different website sources. This works pretty well but I am struggling with one specific source. The issue is that the data-string is not bound by a clear html tag `<>` which means that I somehow need to split the data manually. If have done this before as well with preg but for the example below I struggle to find a solution.

Example of the html data:

```
<div class="column8 gerechten">

<h1>Dagschotels</h1>    

<img src="http://emmaseetcafe.nl/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/voorgerecht2.jpg" class="attachment-fullwidth wp-post-image" alt="dagschotel" />        

<p>Elke week heeft Emma&#8217;s nieuwe dagschotels op het menu staan. Een dagschotel is te bestellen voor € 9,00-. Alle dagschotels zijn ook als kinderdagschotel te verkrijgen voor slechts €5,-. Reserveren voor een daghap is mogelijk, zolang de voorraad strekt.<br />
<br/></p>
<p><strong>28-02</strong>Pasta Tonno<br />
<strong>1-03</strong> Stampot andijvie met slavink<br />
<strong>2-03</strong> Gyros wrap met gebakken aardappelen<br />
</br><br />
<strong>7-03</strong> Erwtensoep met roggebrood<br />
<strong>8-03</strong> Köfte met friet en salade<br />
<strong>9-03</strong> Kipschnitzel met spinazie en gekookte aardappelen<br />
</br><br />
<strong>14-03</strong> Sjasliek met rijst<br />
<strong>15-03</strong> Kipsaté met nasi<br />
<strong>16-03</strong> Scholfilet met friet en gemengde groenten<br />
</br><br />
<strong>21-03</strong> Lente pasta ( verschillende lente groenten)<br />
<strong>22-03</strong> Taco&#8217;s met friet en salade<br />
<strong>23-03</strong> Kip kerrie met rijst<br />
</br><br />
<strong>28-03</strong> Schnitzel met friet en salade<br />
<strong>29-03</strong> Gehaktbal met friet en rode kool<br />
<strong>30-03</strong> Visstoofpotje met aardappelpuree</p>
<p><br/><br />
<strong>ZOLANG DE VOORAAD STREKT</strong><br />
RESERVEREN VAN DAGSCHOTELS IS MOGELIJK<br />
DAGSCHOTEL KOST € 9,00</p>
```

The required output I need before post processing is something like:

Array = ["28-02 Pasta Tonno",
        "1-03 Stampot andijvie met slavink",
        "7-03 Erwtensoep met roggebrood"]
etc.

### Update

I managed to isolate all the dates with simple dom which worked because there all enclosed by the `<strong>` tag. I used the following code:

```
             $html = file_get_html('http://emmaseetcafe.nl/menukaarten/dagschotels/', false, $this->getStreamContext());
             // start to find the meals


             // gets the main dish
             foreach ($html->find('div[class=column8 gerechten]') as $container) {
                foreach ($container->find('p') as $p) {
                            $temp[] = $p->innertext;

             }
        }

    $temp = $temp[1];



    $html = str_get_html($temp);

    foreach ($html->find('strong') as $strong) {
        $temp_dates[] = $strong->innertext;

    }
```

The result is an array with all the dates in dd-mm .

So now what remains is to isolate the actual meals from the following text string:

```
'<strong>02-05</strong> Schnitzel met champignonsaus friet en salade<br /> <strong>03-05</strong> Mexicaanse wrap met friet<br /> <strong>04-05</strong> Pasta Tonno<br /> </br><br /> <strong>09-05</strong> Gegrilde paprika met couscous<br /> <strong>10-05</strong> Thaise Curry met rijst<br /> <strong>11-05</strong> Pasta AOP<br /> </br><br /> <strong>16-05</strong> Couscous met gegrilde kipfilet en geroosterde paprika<br /> <strong>17-05</strong> Tartaar met gebakken ui , frietjes en doperwten<br /> <strong>'... (length=955)
```

### Update 2

I finally managed to solve it myself. I moved away from the simple dom at the end for the last part to remove the strong and the broken `<br />` tag.

```
       //var_dump($meal_string);
    $meal_array = explode("<br />",$meal_string);


    foreach ($meal_array as $meal){
        $meals_no_tags[]= strip_tags($meal);   // strip all php / html tags         
    }


    // structure the data by removing emply items

    foreach ($meals_no_tags as $meal_item){
        if (strlen($meal_item)>3){
        $meal_temp[] = $meal_item;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Although it's possible to do it with regexps, I'd advice to go for HTML parser - it'll be a more reliable solution.

Comment: Mandatory reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454

Answer (score 2):

You would be best using a HTML parser rather than anything else (as pointed out in comment).  This allows you to use the document structure to get at the data rather than relying on content.

The following code uses DOMDocument and it's ability to load HTML.  Although there are some slight problems with the document fragment you give, it's possible to ignore them as they don't form part of the structure your interested in ( tags `</br>` for example).

The code uses XPath to find the `<strong>` tags in the second paragraph as the labels and then gets the text by fetching the next element of the document.

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$content = file_get_contents("e.html");
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$xml->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="utf-8" ?>'.$content);
$xp = new DOMXPath($xml);
$labels = $xp->query("//div/p[2]//strong");
foreach ( $labels as $label )   {
    $text = (string)$label->nextSibling->nodeValue;
    echo (string)$label->nodeValue."=".$text.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Which outputs...

```
28-02=Pasta Tonno
1-03= Stampot andijvie met slavink
2-03= Gyros wrap met gebakken aardappelen
7-03= Erwtensoep met roggebrood
8-03= Köfte met friet en salade
9-03= Kipschnitzel met spinazie en gekookte aardappelen
14-03= Sjasliek met rijst
15-03= Kipsaté met nasi
16-03= Scholfilet met friet en gemengde groenten
21-03= Lente pasta ( verschillende lente groenten)
22-03= Taco’s met friet en salade
23-03= Kip kerrie met rijst
28-03= Schnitzel met friet en salade
29-03= Gehaktbal met friet en rode kool
30-03= Visstoofpotje met aardappelpureeLente pasta ( verschillende lente groenten)
22-03= Taco’s met friet en salade
23-03= Kip kerrie met rijst
28-03= Schnitzel met friet en salade
29-03= Gehaktbal met friet en rode kool
30-03= Visstoofpotje met aardappelpuree
```

As the above HTML may be part of a larger document, you could change the XPath expression to make sure it fetches the right `<div>` element.  You can either use

```
//div[h1/text()="Dagschotels"]/p[2]//strong
```

Which is based on the title, or

```
//div[@class="column8 gerechten"]/p[2]//strong
```

Which is based on the class of the `<div>` element.

Comment: I prefer not to use xpath as the page my change over time and this the path does not work anymore. The same thing applies to some extend for Simple DOM as well but my experience is that the name of the div container that contains the data is pretty stable. Anyhow I will look into this one as it does offer a solution! :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This will give you an idea:

```
$string = preg_replace('/\s{1,}/', ' ', $string);

preg_match_all('/<strong>(.*?)<br \/>/', $string, $array);



 for($i = 0; $i < count($array[1]); $i++){

  $results[] = strip_tags($array[1][$i]);


}

array_pop($results);

print_r($results);
```